# WiFi-driver not Found in Mini PC (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I purchased **mini PC** yesterday with pre-installed licence version Windows 10. Bluetooth, WiFi and Ethernet are working fine.

When I install Ubuntu (18.04) on my mini-PC it doesn't show WiFi.
The Bluetooth and Ethernet is working fine in Ubuntu but WiFi is not.
I tried a lot to find WiFi driver but not getting WiFi.

Please suggest me a right way to install WiFi driver.

Here I attached a link of mini PC which I used.

[Mini Pc Portable Win10 Computer Windows10 Intel Mini Pc - Alibaba.com](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Mini-PC-Portable-Win10-Computer-Windows10_60437432087.html?spm=a2700.8443308.0.0.13603e5fxnTnRT)

attached screenshot of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc7CA.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I try lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 this command. but not get any output.

Comment: I suspect this is one of those with the WiFi in SDIO. Please wait for answers from others.

Comment: A later kernel may be all it takes.  I needed a 4.19+ for my (different) SDIO device to be fully working with standard repo files.

Comment: Please post in your question the output of  the terminal command  
dmesg | grep -i firm  
so we can see exactly what firmware your system is trying to load.

Answer (score 1):

Try in a terminal:

> sudo cp /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.AP6212.txt /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.txt

Then reboot.

If the wifi specs for this pc are listed correctly in the link you provided, ubuntu is looking for the brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.txt, but for what ever reason it is in the firmware folder as brcmfmac43430-sidio.AP6212.txt. This command will simply make a renamed copy of that file.

It's hard to say if this will work without the output of:

> dmesg | grep brcm

(maybe add it to the question)

Also you may want to check [linuxium's isorespin.sh](http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/06/customizing-ubuntu-isos-documentation.html). It can be used to create .iso's of ubuntu and many other distributions specifically for these atom single board computers, including wifi and audio.

*Edit*
brcmfmac43430-sidio.AP6212.txt is installed by isorespin and does not come preinstalled on ubuntu. It could probably be downloaded from somewhere, however isorespin adds a lot of other functionality like audio and some specific kernel parameters. A prespun version of ubuntu is available [here](https://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/search/label/ISOs). However I would recommend creating a lubuntu or xfce version for your mini pc because it has very limited memory.

Comment: Don't you mean ...bin instead of ...txt on your filenames? Anyway, the brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.bin should be present anyway.  Try dmesg | grep -i firm to see any missing firmware complaints.

Comment: Nope, I mean .txt. The .bin file may very well be present, but the .txt file is not.

Comment: This method consistently works for for the dual wifi/bluetooth ap6212, for the wifi only ap6212 the name change is not necessary. Ubuntu does not come with brcmfmac43430 or the a0(wifi+bluetooth) firmware. It can be downloaded as the package rtl8723bt, not available in the repositories.

Comment: The claimed device is Broadcom, not realtek, so I doubt the rtl8723bt package has any relevance.  The package linux-firmware supplies both the .bin versions of of the  brcmfmac43430 firmware.  .txt is not a standard extension for any firmware in linix-firmware. The 8723bs is the realtek version of the sdio firmware, but that's not for the ap6212.

Comment: The ap6212 is a a wireless chip on a a realtek board that uses Broadcom firmware. The chips are used in atom based single board PC's, I have two, the op has one

Comment: I mean, I don't know what to tell you. The physical board on both my PC's has an ampak ap6212 wireless chip, the bios list it as it as rtl8723bs, the rtk8723bt package definitely installs brcmfmac43430-sidio.AP6212.txt  and when I change the name to brcmfmac43430a0-sidio.txt my wireless card works. If you have some other experience that is different or beneficial to the op's issue maybe you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I hope the OP will post the requested output for the greps on dmesg and answer the question which firmware (if any) his hardware needs. An rtl8723bs chip should have working wifi out of the box on the 4.15 kernel (although not bluetooth).  Canonical did write a driver for Intel for the 8723bs and shipped it with their small compute stick -- that driver must have builtin firmware, since there's no dmesg firmware load message. That driver was for kernel 3.13, but worked until recently through kern 4.4 (kernel header fix).The current 8723bs driver needs separate firmware,from linux-firmware pkg.

Comment: You mean the intel atom compute stick with ubuntu 14.04 that intel, not canonical provided proprietary drivers for, but only for 14.04?

Comment: Ubuntu does ship with the .bin built into the kernel these days. However a .txt file is required to define parameters for specific hardware and it does not come with ubuntu. You have to find it and manually install it. The one that linuxiums isorespin installs via the rtk8723bt package is specifically for the intel atom board wich has the ap6212 chip. Maybe if someone were to buy a realtek wireless card with that chip it would just work in ubuntu, I don't know, I've never tried it. I do know however, that it does not work out of the box on with the Intel atom.

Answer (score 0):

I have bought an ACEPC T11 8/128Gb.
I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and everything worked fine but WiFi.
I found that the chipset is RTL8821CU even if it is somehow shown as Broadcom.
I tried many fixes with no results.
Finally I fixed the issue.

I fixed the issue with:

1. `git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821cu.git`
2. `cd rtl8821cu`
3. `sudo ./dkms-install.sh`
4. Reboot

Comment: Commenting here since google search led me here. I just solved this on an acepc t11 without requiring an internet connection (ethernet was unavailable).  I fortuitously noticed that "acepc-t8" was mentioned in one of the paths, so I copied it to the location revealed by `sudo dmesg | grep brcm -C3`: 

`sudo cp /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.acepc-t8.txt /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt`

Followed by reboot, and it worked!!

Comment: @mgsloan that worked for me as well. It would be great if you could create a separate answer with that solution - then we can give you proper upvotes!